# How can I fix the error saying "Unsupported use of the '=' operator."

Tags: matlab, image-processing

First of all, I am MATLAB beginner.

I got stuck with this error:

> Error: File: Function1.m Line: 31 Column: 8
> Unsupported use of the '=' operator. To compare values for equality, use '=='. To specify name-value arguments, check that name is a valid identifier with no surrounding quotes.

The highlighted line is at the very bottom of my code like `If R > = Threshold`

Also, the End line got an error, too

> Line 34: The End operator must be used within an array index expression

How can I fix the errors?

My code:

```
function [EdgeImg, IndexImg] = Function1(InputImg, Threshold)
Four masks for the entire image
H = [-1 -1 -1; 2 2 2; -1 -1 -1];
V = H';
D45 = [2 -1 -1; -1 2 -1; -1 -1 2];
D135 = [-1 -1 2; -1 2 -1; 2 -1 -1];
Compute edge strengths and orientations using the four masks
R1 = imfilter(InputImg, H, 'symmetric');
R2 = imfilter(InputImg, V, 'symmetric');
R3 = imfilter(InputImg, D45, 'symmetric');
R4 = imfilter(InputImg, D135, 'symmetric');
%Initial Edgelmg and Indexlmh
EdgeImg=zero(size(InputImg));                    
IndexImg=len*ones(size(InpuImg));
%Now, loop applied through the pixels at edge using for
for k=1:s(Intlmg,1)
  for m =1:s(Intlmg,2)
  end
  EdgeImg(IndxImg==len)=0;
  figure;
  subplot(1,2,1,0);
  show(EdgeImg,img);
  subplot(1,2,2,0);
  show(IndexeImg,img);
end
[R,jip] = maximize([R1(k,m),R2(k,m),R3(k,m),R4(k,m)
If R > = Threshold    
  EdgeImg(k,m)=R;
  IndexImg(k,m)=jip;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`> =` with a space in the middle is not valid MATLAB syntax. To assess "greater than or equal to" there should not be a space before the equals sign, i.e. `>=`. Similarly "less than or equal to" is `<=`.

`a >= b` and `a <= b` are synonymous with `ge(a,b)` and `le(a,b)` respectively if you want their function form instead.

Please see the [documentation here.](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ge.html)

Comment: @user58066 Also, [`if`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html) should be lower-case